# 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional' value when I try to close all keyboards in a view

Tags: swift, xcode

I have put a full-screen size invisible button behind of all objects(like textfield, picker.. ) to close opened keyboard. I call below function when the button is clicked:

```
func hideKeyboard() {
    for view in self.contentViewOutlet.subviews {
        if let tField = view as? UITextField {
            tField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error after I click the button:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I roughly know what does it mean but I couldn't write a solution. (Actually, this `hideKeyboard()` function was working fine. It starts to give an error after I add `UIPickerView`)

Comment: You're saying that you get an error when you click a button. But you show us a code that hides the keyboard. What line causes an error?

Comment: @Cristik why do you think it's a duplicate? This questing is not about the meaning of the error.

Comment: @YuryImashev button calls hideKeyboard() function. And i get an error in this line: for view in self.contentViewOutlet.subviews (Thanks !)

Comment: @Cristik Of course, I read some of them first but I couldn't write a solution. It is about ability of writing correct syntax. I am trying to learn

Comment: This code crashes if `contentViewOutlet` is `nil`. Check that.

Comment: @mannyCalavera there is an answer to the question I mentioned that says about unconnected outlets.

Comment: I have copied the source code of this page from another page. I forgot to create outlet for view like you said Vadian and Cristik. And it is better if I write it with guard like you said @YuryImashev. Thanks!!

Comment: If you just want to the currently editing field to resignFirstResponder, use `view.endEditing(force: Bool)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `contentViewOutlet` is an `Outlet` so it might be nil, but it's implicitly unwrapped. And you get this error because when you tap a button, this object is `nil`. To avoid the crash, change your code to

```
func hideKeyboard() {
    guard let contentView = self.contentViewOutlet else { return }
    for view in contentView.subviews {
        if let tField = view as? UITextField {
            tField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

After that, your method won't do anything if `contentViewOutlet` is `nil`.

Comment: This just avoids the crash. This does not fix the problem. Why is `self.contentViewOutlet` nil? Fix that problem instead of working around it.

Comment: @rmaddy Agree. I've thought about that too. But there was no question about how to fix this problem and not enough info to give some advice so I decided to simply help to explain the problem and show how to avoid the crash itself.